# How to use ViteJs Glob Import in NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vite

I'm looking for a way to use ViteJs Glob Import in NextJs.

I'm working on NextJs and I found the [Glob Import](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import) function in ViteJs really useful.

I tried to find a way to be able to use it in NexJs but it didn't work. Is there a way I can use it in NexJs?